# Getting Dependency Injection of a hosted service

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-hosted-services

I have the following code:

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IAvailabilityWorker, AvailabilityWorker>();
builder.Services.AddHostedService<AvailabilityWorker>();
```

There is a timer in the service with a public function void set_last_time(DateTime time)

But I can't seem to get the dependency injection working.
If I inject IAvailabilityWorker into the constructor it works but the time is set for another instance besides the singleton one. Even though there shouldn't be.
If I try injecting AvailabilityWorker itself, it only works if I use it without Interface

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<AvailabilityWorker>();
```

But I need the interface registration for testing.

How can I get it working while keeping the interface tied to the implementation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are dealing with is a problem commonly known as [Torn Lifestyle](https://docs.simpleinjector.org/en/latest/tornlifestyle.html). The lifestyle of `AvailabilityWorker` is said to be torn, because it is registered twice; once as singleton and a second time as transient. This is because `AddHostedService` under the covers calls `AddTransient`.

To ensure a single `AvailabilityWorker` instance to exist for the lifetime of your application, you should change the registrations to the following:

```cs
Services.AddSingleton<AvailabilityWorker>();
Services.AddSingleton<IAvailabilityWorker>(
    c => c.GetRequiredService<AvailabilityWorker>());
Services.AddSingleton<IHostedService>(
    c => c.GetRequiredService<AvailabilityWorker>());
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had the
`Services.AddSingleton<AvailabilityWorker>();
Services.AddSingleton<IHostedService>(
    c => c.GetRequiredService<AvailabilityWorker>());`
Pattern already but didn't know you could do it with the interface too.